# Visual Studio Output location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am working on a VCL/C# and was wondering if it was possible to, when receiving errors click on said line, bringing me to the directory and file of said error.

[image: Output]

Is there anyway to right click, go to location or something? Is this even possible?

Cheers!

Comment: It works fine if can configure output format to "file_name(line number)" (similar to C/C# build or find), I don't think it is possible to change VS to accept more output formats.

Comment: I meant, clicking on the file path say at Line: 0027 and it will bring me to the file itself. (sy_all_web.vcl)

Comment: @leonardchan i dont think VS provide any such facility to directly goto the file by right clicking on the error.